# Form validation not working in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is jQuery form validation (html, css and jQuery) but the code isn't work all the if statement and the error message I can't fix it.

```js
$("#validationForm").submit(function(event) {
  var errorMessage = "";
  event.preventDefault();

  function
  isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
    var pattern = new RegExp(/^((([a-z]|\d|
[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([az]|\
d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])
+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-
\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-
\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-
\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|
[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-
\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-
\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|
[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF
\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-
\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?$/i);
    return pattern.test(emailAddress);
  };

  if (!isValidEmailAddress($("#email").val())) {
    errorMessage = "<br />Please enter a
valid email address";
  }
  if (!$.isNumeric($("#phone").val())) {
    errorMessage = errorMessage + "<br />Please enter a valid phone number";
  }
  if ($("#pass1").val() != $("#pass2").val()) {
    errorMessage = errorMessage + "<br />Please enter matching passwords";
  }
  if (errorMessage == "") {
    alert("Success!");
  } else {
    $("#error").html(errorMessage);
  }
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
input {
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
label {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 7px;
}
#submitButton {
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}
#error {
  color: red;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="error"></div>
    <form id="validationForm">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input name="email" id="email" />
      <label for="phone">Telephone</label>
      <input name="phone" id="phone" />
      <label for="pass">Password</label>
      <input name="pass" type="password" id="pass1" />
      <label for="pass">Confirm Password</label>
      <input name="pass" type="password" id="pass2" />
      <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: You could begin with what exactly you want to achieve, then explain what the code does or fails to do. You could also explain what you already tried to debug it. Otherwise noone will be very inclined to dig into that monstrous regex. Aren't there easier ways out there to validate an email address, if that's actually what you want to do?

Comment: Please use proper indents as your code is hard to read otherwise. Please remove all information that is not relevant here (like CSS). And raise a clear question!

Answer (score 0):

If it is HTML5, and you're expecting end-users' browsers to be supporting HTML5 engines, you can use appropriate type attributes for the `input` elements:

```js
$("#validationForm").on('submit', function(event) {
  var errorMessage = "";
  event.preventDefault();

  if (!$.isNumeric($("#phone").val())) {
    errorMessage = errorMessage + "<br />Please enter a valid phone number";
  }
  if ($("#pass1").val() !== $("#pass2").val()) {
    errorMessage = errorMessage + "<br />Please enter matching passwords";
  }
  if (errorMessage == "")
    alert("Success!");
  else
    $("#error").html(errorMessage);
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: helvetica;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
input {
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
label {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 7px;
}
#submitButton {
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}
#error {
  color: red;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="error"></div>
    <form id="validationForm">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input name="email" id="email" type='email' required />
      <label for="phone">Telephone</label>
      <input name="phone" id="phone" type='tel' required />
      <label for="pass">Password</label>
      <input name="pass" type="password" id="pass1" required />
      <label for="pass">Confirm Password</label>
      <input name="pass" type="password" id="pass2" />
      <input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
```

Please note, I've used `type='email'` and `type='tel'` accordingly. Also, I've put the fields to be `required` by default. This way, the browser itself will ask the user to not leave the fields blank.